API management policy - backend based on agency label
I need to implement a policy for forwading the request to the right backend based on something in the URL (agencycode)
For example,

url http://tst.my.api.identity.xxx.com/int/my/v1/#AGENCYCODE#/system/ping
apim API url suffix: "int/my/v1"
backend operation: "/system/ping"

I want to use something like https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/master/examples/Random%20load%20balancer.policy.xml

Given http://tst.my.api.identity.xxx.com/int/my/v1/#AGENCYCODE#/system/ping extract #AGENCYCODE#
Rewrite http://tst.my.api.identity.xxx.com/int/my/v1/#AGENCYCODE#/system/ping to http://tst.my.api.identity.xxx.com/int/my/v1/system/ping
If #AGENCYCODE# == "AABB1" --> set-backend-service = http://10.10.10.1:8080
If #AGENCYCODE# == "AABB2" --> set-backend-service = http://10.10.10.2:8080

I don't know

how to extract #AGENCYCODE# from url
how to rewrite the url removing #AGENCYCODE#

Thanks!

Can you specify your requirement with some screenshot? Which 5 letters you want to extract? provide the policy you have tried and also share the error message

Sorry, I wrote  and Stackoverflow did not displayed it...

Can you please share the policy which you have tried

what would be your expected backend url?

what do you mean by I need to choose a set-backend-service based on #AGENCYCODE# (set-variabile in policy)

I rewrote the post to make it more clear.

You can use the policy given below to extract AGENCYCODE and  rewriting the Url.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="agencyCode" value="@(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path, @"(?<=/int/my/v1/)(.*)(?=/system/ping)").Value)" />
        <rewrite-uri template="/int/my/v1/system/ping" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@((string)context.Variables["agencyCode"] == "AABB1")">
                <set-backend-service base-url="http://10.10.10.1:8080" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@((string)context.Variables["agencyCode"] == "AABB2")">
                <set-backend-service base-url="http://10.10.10.2:8080" />
            </when>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

Trace-



